# How would I substring my value 6 decimal places

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0

Is there a way to substring my value 6 places after decimal?

So if I have

```
<xsl:value-of select="100.1234567890" />
```

Is there a way to make it

```
"100.123456"
```

Comment: See the [`format-number`](https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt#format-number) function. Unfortunately, it is defined in terms of the JDK 1.1 DecimalFormat class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your value is a *number*, not a *string*. The easy way to trim it to 6 decimal places is to **floor** it, not **substring** it:

```
<xsl:value-of select="floor(100.1234567890 * 1000000) div 1000000"/>
```

returns:

```
100.123456
```

---

To achieve the same thing through string manipulation, you could do:

```
<xsl:variable name="n" select="'100.1234567890'" />
<xsl:value-of select="substring($n, 1, string-length(substring-before($n, '.')) + 7)"/>
```